# Using array to convert MapResult to an array

Tags: templates, d

I'm having a bit of trouble using `array` from `std.array` to convert a `MapResult` to a specific array type. My problem is as follows:

I have an array `a` of objects, each of which has a publically-accessible field `val`. I would like to use `map` from `std.algorithm` to go over `a` and return an array of all the values of the `val` members. My code looks something like this:

```
import std.algorithm:map;
import std.array:array;
//import for my object type, which I call Box here

ulong[] fun (Box[] a) {
return array!(ulong[])(map!(function ulong(Box x) {return x.val;})(a);
}
```

However, when I try to do this, the compiler gives me an error saying that `array` cannot deduce the function from the argument types `!(ulong[])(MapResult!(_funcliteral3,Box[]))`. Does that mean that `MapResult`s aren't ranges, and is there a way to get what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually it means that the compiler believed that `(ulong[])(MapResult!(_funcliteral3,Box[]))` was the template parameter instead of `ulong[]`

nest your parenthesis properly and it should be fixed

```
return array!(ulong[])(map!(function ulong(Box x) {return x.val;})(a));
```